# arduino and esp8266 interface

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266

I want to send some AT commands to esp8266 using arduino and get the reply from serial monitor. this is the code:(the purpose of this code is to update a thingspeak channel)

```
 #include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial esp8266(3,2);
#define ID "user"
#define PASS "pass"
String apiKey = "apikey";
void setup() {
  Serial.setTimeout(5000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
 // delay(1000);
     String command6="AT+RST";

  esp8266.println(command6);
  if(esp8266.available())
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      char c=esp8266.read();
      Serial.write(c);          
    }
  }
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
 delay(2000);
  String command="\nAT";

  esp8266.println(command);
  if(esp8266.available())
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      char c=esp8266.read();
      Serial.write(c);          
    }
  } 

   String cmd = "\nAT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += "144.212.80.11"; // api.thingspeak.com
  cmd += "\",80";

  esp8266.println(cmd);
  if(esp8266.available())
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      char c=esp8266.read();
      Serial.write(c);          
    }
  }
   delay(3000);
  String command3="\nAT+CIPSEND=200";

  esp8266.println(command3);
  if(esp8266.available())
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      char c=esp8266.read();
      Serial.write(c);          
    }
  }
    delay(1000);

    String getStr = "GET /update?api_key=";
    getStr += apiKey;
    getStr += "&field1=10";

  esp8266.println(getStr);
  esp8266.println("\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r");
  if(esp8266.available())
  {
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      char c=esp8266.read();
      Serial.write(c);          
    }
  }
  delay(15000);

}
```

user and pass are my wifi username and password. the problem is, the esp8266 responds "ok" to at commands but when it gets to the last parts, it gives me this:

```
A))-R¤%%JHÕ¨TUPZ="TCP","144.212.80.11",80
CONNECT
OK
ERROR
AT+CIPSEND=200
OK
> GET /update?api_key=apikey&field1=10
CAT
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","144.212.80.11",80
AT+CIPSEND=200
GET /update?api_key=apikey&field1=10
AT
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","144.212.80.11",80
busy s...
```

i have put a few delays inside the code but after it inserts the GET it gets back to the loop runs the program again with no delays and then esp8266 resets itself.

Comment: Can't help on this occasion, but I'd like to advise you not to post your private API Keys on a public site.

Comment: thanks :D
I think I kinda found why its not working, I'm storing too much in the SRAM, cause strings take too much space, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You can't have a look at storing data in EEPROM, see [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM). Another halfway option is to add an SDcard/microSD card reader to your arduino. From a pragmatic point of view, if you can easily get your hands on a board with more memory (e.g. Arduino Mega), go for it and save time (throwing money at the problem).

Comment: yes i tested progmem but seems like its only for constant strings, the strings in my code are gonna have some variables like room temprature etc..

Comment: upgrade to NodeMCU lua in esp. ESP has plenty of RAM and a huge flash (in comparison to arduino)

Comment: thanks. i solved it. the problem was that i didn't wait for esp to send ok at the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Besides waiting for the OK, you also need to make sure that you are using the right IP address for ThingSpeak. The offical static IP for ThingSpeak is 184.106.153.149 found here (http://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/channel-settings.html#endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

Try using /n after the At command not before and also check the correct format for AT+CIPSEND

> GET http://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=KTQXXXXXXXXXXXXX&field1=10 HTTP/1.0 \r\n\r\n

try this format

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to keep in mind when working with `ESP8266` communicate over a network.

- 1 The response might not be received in a constant time i.e `100ms`
  or `1ms` etc. there will always be random delay.
- 2 Check if the ESP is not running out of current while making a
  `GET/POST` request.
- 3 Check for every character/escape sequence (`'\r' '\n'` etc.) and
  place them into right place into your "Request" string.

This might help you: [Arduino ESP8266 AT GET Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675858/arduino-esp8266-at-get-request/46048642#46048642)

Thank you. :)